# python function or specifically numpy that returns an array with numbers of repetitions of an item in a row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

the thing that I'm looking for, is a function that given "a" will return "b" by the following:

```
a = numpy.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

which at first 1 shows 4 times in a row, after that 5 shows 5 times, 6 shows 1 time, 5 shows 1 and 2 shows 4 times

and what will return is an array like this:

```
b = numpy.array([4, 5, 1, 1, 4])
```

the function that im looking for will treat 5 this way, even though 5 is in the array "a" 6 times in total, it will count seperately per sequence

it is a very specific, i wrote a function like this, but i want to know if there is in numpy a built-in function like this for fast perfotmance

thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is no built-in function.  However, doing the consecutive count is easy enough.  If you want to see a more general solution, research "run length encoding"

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `bincount` on `cumsum` of nonzero diff:

```
out = np.bincount((np.diff(a)!=0).cumsum())
out[0] += 1
```

Output:

```
array([4, 5, 1, 1, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use additional attributes of `np.diff` to create an array of differences with extra units in both ends added artificially:

```
>>> np.diff(a,prepend=a[0]-1,append=a[-1]+1)
array([ 1,  0,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1, -1, -3,  0,  0,  0,  1])
```

Now this is ready for combination of `np.diff` and `np.nonzero`:

```
x = np.diff(a, prepend=a[0]-1, append=a[-1]+1)
np.diff(np.nonzero(x))
```

Output:

```
array([[4, 5, 1, 1, 4]], dtype=int32)
```

But this is a little bit slower: 3x slower for small array `a` and 25% slower for large array `a = np.random.randint(3,size=10000000)`.